# MySQL For loop? Is it possible?

Tags: mysql

I have a query in MySQL that works well. It runs over one year of data at a time.

```
2020-01-01 to 2021-01-01
```

The problem is, it needs to run in monthly increments. So it needs to run as:

```
2020-01-01 to 2021-01-01
2020-02-01 to 2021-02-01
2020-03-01 to 2021-03-01
2020-04-01 to 2021-04-01
etc...
```

The only way I can think about doing this at the minute is one month at a time. I set the FROM and TO timeperiods at the top of the script.

But to run it for 3 years, it needs to run 36 times, if I use this method.

Is there a way to loop through dates & run the query over and over again, so I dont need to do it manually?

```
SET @tp = '2019/01/01';
SET @tp2 = '2020/01/01';
```

Thanks

Comment: did any of the given answers work?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a for loop if you just want to add one year to all timestamps.
I don't know the data-structure, but somthing like :

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET yourDate = DATE_ADD(yourDate , INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Recursive CTE to achieve the result without using loops or stored procedures. Just enter the correct start and end dates. This is the code:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte1 AS 
(SELECT '2019-01-01' as firstdate, '2020-01-01' as seconddate
UNION ALL
SELECT (firstdate + INTERVAL 1 MONTH),(seconddate + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) FROM cte1 WHERE firstdate < '2022-12-01' AND seconddate < '2023-12-01'
)
SELECT CONCAT(firstdate, ' to ',seconddate) as FullRange FROM cte1;
```

If we run it, It returns:

[image: fgd]

..............

[image: fgds]

Extra:

You can also set limits using variables: The same result

FullCode:

```
SET @tp = '2019-01-01';
SET @tp_end = '2022-12-01';
SET @tp2 = '2020-01-01';
SET @tp2_end = '2023-12-01';
WITH RECURSIVE cte1 AS 
(SELECT @tp as firstdate, @tp2 as seconddate
UNION ALL
SELECT (firstdate + INTERVAL 1 MONTH),(seconddate + INTERVAL 1 MONTH) FROM cte1 WHERE firstdate < @tp_end AND seconddate < @tp2_end
)
SELECT CONCAT(firstdate, ' to ',seconddate) as FullRange FROM cte1;
```